# Как удалить записи в MySQL у которых значение поля больше чем определенное число?

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица (Pole1, Pole2):

//MySQL

[image: пример таблицы]

Мне нужно удалить все записи, значение которых в Pole2 больше, чем 5000

Вот такой результат хотелось бы получить
[image: Желаемый результат]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DELETE FROM table WHERE pole2 > 5000;

Это самый типовой sql